# When displaying data from mysql in python, time and date column looks almost unreadable.. Is there a way to display it in date and time format?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, mysql-python, python-datetime

I want to display a mysql table in `Python`, when I use the `"Select * from table"` command, the time and date column is displayed as a bunch of numbers with commas in between. Its hard to read them as date and time. My code is;

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import mysql.connector as sq

s = sq.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Zxcvbnm*1", database="ip_project")
if s.is_connected():
    print("Sucess")

try:
    print("Displaying Attendance..")
    cur=s.cursor() 
    d="""select * from main"""
    cur.execute(d)
    data=cur.fetchall()
    for i in data:
        print(i)

except Exception:
    print("Something went wrong.. try again")
```

And the output is;

```
Sucess
Displaying Attendance..
(1, 'Talia', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 16, 16, 28, 12))
```

I want to get rid of "datetime.datetime" and want it to look somewhat like

```
(1,'Talia',2021:8:16 16:28:12)
```

Is it possible? Also sorry for messy work. Just a beginner here, need this for school project.

Comment: When you do `print(i)` you do not specify the way you want to see the output, so you get the Python default, which is to display the tuple as it would be represented as a literal in Python code. If you want to get rid of `datetime.datetime`, you need to extract the datetime from the tuple, as `i[2]`, then convert that to a string in the format you want, as `i[2].isoformat()`. If you want some other format, use `i[2].strftime(...)`. What you  put in the parens depends on what format you want. You need to look at the documentation for that. So, `print (f"({i[0]}, {i[1]!r}, {i[2].isoformat()})")`

Comment: Thankyou so much! Got it working the way i wanted to with you help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [strftime(format) method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), to create a string representing the time under the control of an explicit format string.